How to set the default keyboard layout for new windows?
In my Windows 11 I have several language packs and keyboard  layouts installed. When I open a new window the system assigns it a language and layout, apparently  for no reason. I  don't see any regularity in this. In the Settings, US English is at the top of the list, and  it is also at the top in the Language bar list.
How do I force the system to always assign it to new windows, without the need for me to switch language each time I open a new window?
Now I see that in my case, the system always chooses one specific language of those installed (the language bar shows this language when I login).
The question is, how do I change it so the system chooses another one of my installed languages?
